# Javascript: empty constructor name for instances of "object properties"

Tags: javascript, constructor, namespaces

I want to namespace my code, so I did this:

```js
let Namespace = {};

Namespace.Func = function (a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
};
Namespace.Func.prototype.getSum = function () {
  return this.a + this.b;
};
```

Then, I created an instance of `Namespace.Func`:

```js
let f = new Namespace.Func(1, 2);
```

Now , I would expect all these lines to be true:

```js
console.log(f.getSum() === 3);
console.log(typeof f === 'object');
console.log(f instanceof Object);
console.log(f instanceof Namespace.Func);
console.log(f.constructor === Namespace.Func);
console.log(f.constructor.name === "Namespace.Func");
```

But the last one is `false`, because `f.constructor.name` is `""`.

Why is that? Can it be fixed?

Here you have the code snippet:

```js
let Namespace = {};

Namespace.Func = function (a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
};
Namespace.Func.prototype.getSum = function () {
  return this.a + this.b;
};

let f = new Namespace.Func(1, 2);

console.log("f.getSum() === 3", f.getSum() === 3);
console.log("typeof f === 'object'", typeof f === 'object');
console.log("f instanceof Object", f instanceof Object);
console.log("f instanceof Namespace.Func", f instanceof Namespace.Func);
console.log("f.constructor === Namespace.Func", f.constructor === Namespace.Func);
console.log("f.constructor.name === 'Namespace.Func'", f.constructor.name === 'Namespace.Func');
console.log('---');
console.log("f.constructor.name", f.constructor.name);
console.log("f.constructor.name === ''", f.constructor.name === '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify function name for your constructor like below:

```
Namespace.Func = function TheNameOfConstructor (a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
};
```

The assert will pass after that like this:

```
console.log(f.constructor.name === "TheNameOfConstructor");
```

Comment: Is there any way of having the constructor name to be "Namespace.Func"? Dots seem not to be accepted.

Comment: Dots in function name are prohibited I guess, so I would suggest to consider using bare function name, without namespace included.